# Updating cabal version on Fedora 25

Tags: cabal, cabal-install

I have cabal already installed on my Fedora OS. 
The current version of cabal is

```
  user@localhost ~]$ cabal --version
  cabal-install version 1.22.9.0
  using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library
```

I want to update cabal to the latest version *Release 1.24.2.0*. But the update is not successful.

```
  user@localhost ~]$ sudo cabal update
  [sudo] password for rajkumar: 
  Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
  Skipping download: Local and remote files match.
```

My ghc version is

```
  user@localhost ~]$ ghc --version
  The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.3
```

Below is the log of the 2 steps above. 
I am seeing in log it says Installed cabal-install-1.24.0.2
Once it is done, still the cabal --version doesn't result in latest version. Any Idea

```
  [user@localhost ~]$ sudo cabal update
  [sudo] password for user: 
  Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org
  [user@localhost ~]$ sudo cabal install cabal-install
  Resolving dependencies...
  Downloading Cabal-1.24.2.0...
  Downloading base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6...
  Configuring base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6...
  Downloading cryptohash-sha256-0.11.100.1...
  Downloading ed25519-0.0.5.0...
  Configuring cryptohash-sha256-0.11.100.1...
  Downloading tar-0.5.0.3...
  Building base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6...
  Building cryptohash-sha256-0.11.100.1...
  Installed base16-bytestring-0.1.1.6
  Configuring Cabal-1.24.2.0...
  Configuring ed25519-0.0.5.0...
  Installed cryptohash-sha256-0.11.100.1
  Building Cabal-1.24.2.0...
  Building ed25519-0.0.5.0...
  Configuring tar-0.5.0.3...
  Installed ed25519-0.0.5.0
  Building tar-0.5.0.3...
  Installed tar-0.5.0.3
  Installed Cabal-1.24.2.0
  Downloading hackage-security-0.5.2.2...
  Configuring hackage-security-0.5.2.2...
  Building hackage-security-0.5.2.2...
  Installed hackage-security-0.5.2.2
  Downloading cabal-install-1.24.0.2...
  Configuring cabal-install-1.24.0.2...
  Building cabal-install-1.24.0.2...
  Installed cabal-install-1.24.0.2
  [user@localhost ~]$ cabal --version
  cabal-install version 1.22.9.0
  using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library 
  [user@localhost ~]$ sudo cabal --version
  [sudo] password for user: 
  cabal-install version 1.22.9.0
  using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library
```

Thanks in advance for your kind suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

According to:
https://github.com/haskell/cabal

> ## Installing Cabal
>
> Assuming that you have a pre-existing, older version of cabal-install, run:
>   
>   `cabal install cabal-install`
>   To get the latest version of cabal-install. (You may want to cabal update first.)

```
cabal update
cabal install cabal-install
```

`cabal update` by itself will only get the current list of packages from Hackage.

Comment: Nick, I followed your suggestion. I do see it is downloading cabal 1.24.0.2. but somehow after the install complete, it still remains in older version. Any idea? Do I need to follow any other steps or missing anything here?

Answer (score 1):

Below steps update the cabal in `~/.cabal/bin` but it does not update the symbolic link at `/usr/bin`

```
 sudo cabal update
 sudo cabal install cabal-install
```

So after that I followed the below steps as well and it helped me.

```
[user@localhost ~]$ which cabal
/usr/bin/cabal
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/cabal
[sudo] password for user: 
[user@localhost ~]$ which cabal
~/.cabal/bin/cabal
[user@localhost ~]$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.24.0.2
compiled using version 1.24.2.0 of the Cabal library 
[user@localhost ~]$ sudo ln -s ~/.cabal/bin/cabal /usr/bin
[sudo] password for user: 
[user@localhost ~]$ which cabal
/usr/bin/cabal
[user@localhost ~]$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.24.0.2
compiled using version 1.24.2.0 of the Cabal library
```